# Custom User Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, cookies

I want to implement custom user authentication. I have username textbox and password textbox also I have button which submits the form.

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("Submit","Profile"))
{

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Username: </td>
            <td>@Html.TextBox("Username")</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password: </td>
            <td>@Html.TextBox("Password")</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
```

When the button is clicked the action method will be invoked.

```
public ActionResult Submit(User user)
        {
            HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("User");
            myCookie["current"] = user.Username;
            myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10);

            Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

All I want is to check if there is no cookie, action methods to be not accessible. If there is a cookie to be accessible.

Comment: Check if the cookie exists in the `Request` and if not, send a `401` response?

Comment: How to send 401 response ?

Comment: `return new HttpUnauthorizedResult()`

Answer (score 0):

As per my comments, something like this should work:

```
var cookie = Request.Cookie["myCookie"];

if (cookie == null)
    return new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

why not to use FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie method for setting coockie and standart [Authorize] attribute ?